# Implementing 'git pull' with libgit2?

Tags: c, git, libgit2

I have [a relatively short Gist](https://gist.github.com/nathan-osman/5157055) which is supposed to use `libgit2` to emulate the functionality of the `git pull` command. Unfortunately, it's not quite working.

In summary, the snippet:

- calls [`git_repository_open()`](http://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/repository/git_repository_open) to open the repository on disk
- calls [`git_remote_load()`](http://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/remote/git_remote_load) to get a `git_remote *` to the remote named "origin"
- calls [`git_remote_connect()`](http://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/remote/git_remote_connect) with the `GIT_DIRECTION_FETCH` flag
- calls [`git_remote_download()`](http://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/remote/git_remote_download) to fetch objects from the remote

According to [`git_remote_stats()`](http://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/remote/git_remote_stats), objects are indeed being fetched. But the working directory doesn't change to reflect the latest commit. I tried adding:

```
git_checkout_head(repo, NULL);
```

...but that made no difference.

Entering:

```
git checkout master
```

...in a terminal results in the following output:

```
Already on 'master'
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
```

How do I fast-forward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run `git pull origin master`

or

`git fetch origin` + `git merge origin/master`

Then means you need the equivalent libgit2 merge function.

merge function is available in libgit2 v0.20

Comment: Actually, there is a WIP (work in progress) branch containing a `git_merge` function. It seems relatively mature and I'm currently looking into using it.

Comment: anything new on this?

Comment: mention libgit2 v0.20

Comment: This is +/- correct; however, you should be careful in cases where local branches (i.e. master) map onto remote branches with different names (e.g. if your local "master" branch mapped to a "devel" branch on the remote.) The complete libgit2 implementation of "pull" would also want look into the config to get the mapping of remote to local branches.