# Implementing Pull with Pygit2

Tags: python, libgit2, pygit2

I am trying to implement some 'porcelain' commands using pygit2. It seems that I have run into a bit of road block while implementing pull. Specifically the easiest pull case, a fast forward.

**Setup:**

I have two git repos. One 'remote' and one 'local'. I make one commit on the remote repo and then create the local repo using pygit2's `clone_repository()`. I make a subsequent commit on the remote and then attempt to run the `pull()` function outlined below.

**My implementation:**

```
def pull(repo, remote_name='origin'):
    for remote in repo.remotes:
        if remote.name == remote_name:
            remote.fetch()
            remote_master_id = repo.lookup_reference('refs/remotes/origin/master').target
            merge_result, _ = repo.merge_analysis(remote_master_id)
            # Up to date, do nothing
            if merge_result & pygit2.GIT_MERGE_ANALYSIS_UP_TO_DATE:
                return
            # We can just fastforward
            elif merge_result & pygit2.GIT_MERGE_ANALYSIS_FASTFORWARD:
                print repo.head.target
                print repo.status()
                master_ref = repo.lookup_reference('refs/heads/master')
                master_ref.set_target(remote_master_id)
                repo.head.set_target(master_ref)
                repo.checkout_head()
                print repo.status()
            elif merge_result & pygit2.GIT_MERGE_ANALYSIS_NORMAL:
                repo.merge(remote_master_id)
                print repo.index.conflicts

                assert repo.index.conflicts is None, 'Conflicts, ahhhh!'
                user = repo.default_signature
                tree = repo.index.write_tree()
                commit = repo.create_commit('HEAD',
                                            user,
                                            user,
                                            'Merge!',
                                            tree,
                                            [repo.head.target, remote_master_id])
                repo.state_cleanup()
            else:
                raise AssertionError('Unknown merge analysis result')
```

[Full Source](https://github.com/MichaelBoselowitz/pygit2-examples/blob/master/examples.py)

After the fast forward bit of my code executes, my index is no longer clean and I have no idea why. Looking at the git-log, it looks successful. My head and the master branch are now pointing at the most recent commit on the remote repo. However, why was `remote_repo_test.txt` modified in the process of running `set_target()`.

**The Outputs:**

The pull print statements:

```
abfe58ce5098e106a14263df725247bc1f4b22d2
{}
{'remote_repo_test.txt': 2}
```

Git log:

```
* commit b1842f03efe959e93ebad197f36d50ee658e71a4
| Author: Michael Boselowitz <xxx>
| Date:   Fri Jan 2 17:21:45 2015 -0500
| 
|     Version 2 of test.txt on remote_repo
| 
| diff --git a/remote_repo_test.txt b/remote_repo_test.txt
| index a1665f0..13f7f3f 100644
| --- a/remote_repo_test.txt
| +++ b/remote_repo_test.txt
| @@ -1,2 +1,4 @@
|  Version 1.
|  
| +Version 2.
| +
|  
* commit abfe58ce5098e106a14263df725247bc1f4b22d2
  Author: Michael Boselowitz <xxx>
  Date:   Fri Jan 2 17:21:45 2015 -0500

      Version 1 of test.txt on remote_repo

  diff --git a/remote_repo_test.txt b/remote_repo_test.txt
  new file mode 100644
  index 0000000..a1665f0
  --- /dev/null
  +++ b/remote_repo_test.txt
  @@ -0,0 +1,2 @@
  +Version 1.
  +
```

Git status:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   remote_repo_test.txt
```

remote_repo_test.txt content:

```
Version 1.
```

**Related Questions without Answers:**

- [pulling and integrating remote changes with pygit2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200789/pulling-and-integrating-remote-changes-with-pygit2)
- [Implementing 'git pull' with libgit2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492375/implementing-git-pull-with-libgit2)
- [Performing a “fast-forward” merge with Rugged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072920/performing-a-fast-forward-merge-with-rugged)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First Solution (Not Recommended):**

You should **not** do this. It is possible to lose work this way. However, it works as a hacky solution.

```
master_ref = repo.lookup_reference('refs/heads/master')
master_ref.set_target(remote_master_id)
# Terrible hack to fix set_target() screwing with the index
repo.reset(master_ref.target, pygit2.GIT_RESET_HARD)
```

[Full source](https://github.com/MichaelBoselowitz/pygit2-examples/blob/268c0ad25f02c288d7bdcf032d0d27afbf799691/examples.py#L58)

**Second Solution:**

This one seems to be promising. After much trial and error, I may have found the solution. If you checkout the tree object you want to target **before** you update the reference it works. The index is clean like what you would expect when running a `git pull` or `git merge`

```
repo.checkout_tree(repo.get(remote_master_id))
master_ref = repo.lookup_reference('refs/heads/master')
master_ref.set_target(remote_master_id)
repo.head.set_target(remote_master_id)
```

[Full source](https://github.com/MichaelBoselowitz/pygit2-examples/blob/68e889e50a592d30ab4105a2e7b9f28fac7324c8/examples.py#L58)

Comment: The problem we are having is that doing this: repo.checkout_tree(repo.get(remote_master_id)) seems to remove local commits. Is it possible to do a merge and not lose local commits somehow?

Comment: @EricVanBezooijen if you have local commits that weren't pushed to the remote then you don't want to perform a fast-forward (which is what this question was referencing)—you'll want to perform a merge. Which if you look at the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27749418/1174287), there's a sample implementation of that in there after the merge analysis.